Gnome, how to remove trailing empty workspace?
I remember for workspaces in an older version of Ubuntu 23.10 is the one I currently have when hovering over the workspace top edge an "X" showed and I could close that workspace. That "X" in wayland does not exist for workspace anymore.
How do I get that functionality back?

Your memory may serve you wrong in this: there has never been a functionality to close a workspace in Gnome Shell.

Either you have automatic workspaces. Then, workspaces are automatically kept to the number that contains windows plus one empty at the end.

When you have windows on a single workspace, the workspace thumbnails on the top are hidden. You still see the empty workspace on the right.
When you have multiple active workspaces, the thumbnails on top are shown.


You can also configure to work with static workspaces. Then it works like it traditionally worked in the majority of desktop environments.


ok thank you, i also somewhat recall that there was no empty workspace and that when dragging an app to a new workspace it was created with a plus or indication of adding a new workspace, i also remember i could reorder them which isnt possible in Ubuntu, maybe i was using Debian that had that feature

If this answer resolved your question, then please show your appreciation by "accepting" it: click the checkmark next to the answer.
